# During an Application Pool recycle are assemblies unloaded from an app domain?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, assemblies, appdomain

Ive just checked AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies before and after an App Pool recycle and it appears that is the case.    I dont understand why some 86 assemblies are loaded in the first instance, i.e. when I deploy the app and then only 28 are loaded after the recycle.

What could be happening?

Comment: is it a dedicated or shared app pool?

Comment: a dedicated application pool. I have specifically created an app pool just for the Website in question. It was previously sharing an app pool with about 5 other Websites when the problem reared its head, but even using a dedicated app pool is not providing any solution.

Comment: Did you find any way to solve the problem? If yes: Could you please share it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [known behavior](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html) of IIS. After IIS recycle, assemblies are loaded on demand.

If you want to get all available assemblies, you can use [`GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) method on the [`System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.aspx) type.

For example :

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
if (HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager)
{
    assemblies = assemblies.Union(BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>());
}
```